# Spring Context classloader from xml

Tags: java, spring, classloader, javabeans, applicationcontext

How get application context classloader from spring xml configuration, to set it like a param for other bean?
From java code I could just

```
@Autowired 
ApplicationContext context
...
{
    ClassLoader classLoader = context.getClassLoader();
}
```

Comment: your question very vague, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Just implement `BeanClassLoaderAware`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not using a container bean?

```java
@bean
public class ClassLoaderHolderBean implements ClassLoaderHolder {
   @Autowired 
   ApplicationContext context;

   @override
   public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
     return context.getClassLoader();
   }
}
```

Then inject this bean where needed.

Comment: Smart solution, thanks.